# Border radius of table not working due to border-collapse property

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, border-radius

My border radius does not show if I have the property of border-collapse on the table tag. I need the border-radius property on and if I remove the border-collapse property I don't get the look I want which is the grey sections to go to the very edge of the table.

What is the solution to this and whats the cause of it?

Thanks in advance

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  /*if i comment out the border-collapse property it then shows my radius*/
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 25px 0;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  min-width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  /*margin is just for demo*/
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

table tr {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #d1d1d1;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

table td {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

table td:first-of-type {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Application</td>
      <td>Natural gas & LPG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Standards</td>
      <td>BS EN ISO 9001:2008 - EN 331:1998</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Connection</td>
      <td>BSP Taper F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finish</td>
      <td>Plated</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

very

Comment: I assume your intent is to remove any space between the border and the inner content yes and also have a radius on the border?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your intention is to not see any spacing between the content background and the border, then simply remove the `border-collapse` and add `border-spacing: 0`. `border-spacing: 0` will not affect the border radius at all and it will also give you the results of no space between the border and the inner content.

In searching it seems there are some anomalies with using collapse and radius together. There are also some work arounds where you use psuedo tags on the tables children specifically to get a radius to work, but why waste all that time when you can just remove the space between the border and its inner content using `border-spacing` which works well with `border-radius`

**EDIT:** *By using psuedo selectors along with `border-space: 0` you can achieve a more pronounced border radius.*

***We want to target each td element that borders the edge of the table element.***
*`table tr td:first-of-type` and `table tr td:last of type` to get the left and right sides. Then we target each subsequent first and last child to get the corners. Lastly, if this is a dynamic table and you will have more than `two` data tables located in the table, add `td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)` on each first and last of type.*

`I don't get the look I want which is the grey sections to go to the very edge of the table.`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  /*add border-spacing: 0     instead of     border-collapse: collapse*/
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 25px 0;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  min-width: 400px;
  /*margin is just for demo*/
  margin: 20px 20px;
}


/* Start psuedo child tags here, targeting each data elements relevant corners and sides */

table tr td:first-of-type {
   border-left: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

table tr td:last-of-type {
   border-right: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

/* :not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
This will get any potential data tables that are added 
that are not sides or corners however, they are border 
data tables on top or bottom */    

table tr:first-of-type td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
  border-top: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}


table tr:last-of-type td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

table tr:first-of-type td:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

table tr:first-of-type td:last-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

table tr:last-of-type td:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

table tr:last-of-type td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-bottom:  1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

/* End Psuedo tags here */

table tr {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #d1d1d1;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

table td {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

table td:first-of-type {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Application</td>
        <td>here is some data</td>
        <td>Natural gas & LPG</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Standards</td>
        <td>some data in between</td>
        <td>BS EN ISO 9001:2008 - EN 331:1998</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Connection</td>
        <td>some data in between</td>
        <td>BSP Taper F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>more tables</td>
        <td>some data in between</td>
        <td>more data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some more data still</td>
        <td>some data in between</td>
        <td>and yet more about this data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Finish</td>
        <td>Plated</td>
        <td>Plated too</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this would work but the top radius on both corners isn't correct, looks like there is white in it? - the bottom corners are perfect? Infact when you zoom in, it shows that he top row overhangs cutting through the top corners giving the white look, show how would I fix this?

Comment: @PaulMaximus I have added a method of targeting each side and corner using psuedo tags to add a more robust border where the radius is more pronounced. Target the first and last of type adding side borders, then fisrt and last of type along with first and last child to get the relevant corners and top and bottom borders.

Comment: @PaulMaximus great, hopefully it will help others as well.